# How can I remove all nodes from a scenekit scene?

Tags: swift, nodes, reset, scenekit

Hi I am trying to remove all nodes from my Scenekit scene but I cannot for the life of me figure out a way.

It seems logical to me that there must be a function for doing this automatically but I cannot find it.

In context, I am trying to remove all nodes so I can reset my scene, which will happen reasonably often. Perhaps there is another way of doing this and I would be fine with that, I'm not stuck with having to remove all nodes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this (assuming you are using Swift):

```
rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
        node.removeFromParentNode()
    }
```

Works for me.

Comment: Note that per the Cocoa conventions it is a programmer error to mutate a collection (the child nodes) while it's being enumerated. I would not recommend doing that.

Answer (score 15):

For me worked like below:

```
sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
node.removeFromParentNode() }
```

Comment: Also you can skip pausing the session

Answer (score 3):

you can either create a new scene or call `-[SCNNode removeFromParentNode]` on every child node of the scene's `rootNode`

Comment: I moved my accepted answer from this to Alans answer, partly because his is clearer but mostly because it is in swift which is what I tagged the question with.

Answer (score 3):

Where you need to remove all of your nodes, call this (if your scene isn't `self`, change it):

```
for (SCNNode *node in [self children]) {
    [node removeFromParent]
}
```

Additionally, if you need to remove each node **except for some**, call this (say, we don't want to remove 3 nodes, and they're named `a`, `b`, and `c`)

```
for (SCNNode *node in [self children]) {
    if (![node.name isEqualToString:@"a"] && ![node.name isEqualToString:@"b"] && ![node.name isEqualToString:@"c"]) {
        [node removeFromParent]
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Modifying a collection while looping through it is not good practice; here's an alternative:

```
while let n = node.childNodes.first { n.removeFromParentNode() }
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, every single answer on the topic I could find features `SCNNode.enumerateChildNodes` method, but using it has a significant downside — it is asynchronous. Meaning you could not be notified when all of node's children had been removed.

Fortunately, there is much more robust approach which takes advantage of [childNodes(passingTest:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407982-childnodes) method. It basically allows you to retrieve all nodes that satisfy a condition, **synchronously**.

So removal of all child nodes could be achieved in two steps:

```swift
// baseNode: SCNNode is defined somewhere in your code

// 1. retrieve all child nodes
let allChildNodes = baseNode.childNodes { _, _ in true }

// 2. remove nodes from their parent
for childNode in allChildNodes {
  childNode.removeFromParentNode()
}
```

Note that we could use the first param of the block for more advanced filtering — say selecting nodes by their name, contents etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in Objective-C (Yes it still exists!)

```
while (self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNodes.count) {
    NSArray<SCNNode *> *nodes = self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNodes;
    [nodes[0] removeFromParentNode];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the simplest way I found to remove all nodes from a scene is:

```
  self.removeAllChildren()
```

This worked well for me in XCode version 7.2

Comment: This method is not available in SceneKit nowadays

Comment: Because this is not a SceneKit but a SpriteKit method