# Remove text node when resetting the session in ARKit 1.5

Tags: swift, arkit

I have slightly modified [Apple's example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience) about recognising images in ARKit 1.5 so that every time an image is recognised I show some text geometry in front of it.

Unfortunately I noticed that when pressing the reset button in the StatusView View, my text geometry doesn't get removed but only repositioned somewhere around the new center of the scene.

Instead if I press the back button (because I embedded the main view controller in a navigation controller in order to start the AR session by means of a button and not automatically as in the example), and start the session again, then everything disappears correctly.

Analysing the code I can affirm that both the reset button and going back and forth from the ViewController trigger the same function as follows

```
func resetTracking() {

    guard let referenceImages = loadImageReferences() else {
        fatalError("Missing expected asset catalog resources.")
    }

    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.detectionImages = referenceImages
    configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
    session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])

    statusViewController.scheduleMessage("Look around to detect images", inSeconds: 7.5, messageType: .contentPlacement)
}
```

As I mentioned, this function is called either in the `ViewDidLoad` method of the ViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sceneView.delegate = self
    sceneView.session.delegate = self

    // debug scene to see feature points and world's origin ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints,
    self.sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showWorldOrigin]

    // Hook up status view controller callback(s).
    statusViewController.restartExperienceHandler = { [unowned self] in
        self.restartExperience()
    }   
}

func restartExperience() {
    guard isRestartAvailable else { return }
    isRestartAvailable = false

    statusViewController.cancelAllScheduledMessages()

    resetTracking()

    // Disable restart for a while in order to give the session time to restart.
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
        self.isRestartAvailable = true
    }
}
```

and also upon pressing the reset button in StatusViewController.

```
@IBAction private func restartExperience(_ sender: UIButton) {
    restartExperienceHandler()
}

var restartExperienceHandler: () -> Void = {}
```

for further reference, I create may text as follows

```
func createBillboardText(text: String, position: SCNNode, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat){

    let newText = splitString(every: 10, string: text)
    let textGeometry = SCNText(string: newText, extrusionDepth: 1.0)

    textGeometry.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: textGeometry)

    // Update object's pivot to its center
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44828764/arkit-placing-an-scntext-at-a-particular-point-in-front-of-the-camera
    let (min, max) = textGeometry.boundingBox
    let dx = min.x + 0.5 * (max.x - min.x)
    let dy = min.y + 0.5 * (max.y - min.y)
    let dz = min.z + 0.5 * (max.z - min.z)
    textNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(dx, dy, dz)
    textNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.005, 0.005, 0.005)

    let plane = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)
    let blueMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    blueMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
    blueMaterial.transparency = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    plane.firstMaterial = blueMaterial
    let parentNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane) // this node will hold our text node

    let yFreeConstraint = SCNBillboardConstraint()
    yFreeConstraint.freeAxes = [.Y] // optionally
    parentNode.constraints = [yFreeConstraint] // apply the constraint to the parent node

    parentNode.addChildNode(textNode)

    position.addChildNode(parentNode)

    sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

}
```

called in the `func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)` method as `self.createBillboardText(text: message, position: node, width: referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: referenceImage.physicalSize.height )`

I also found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738551/how-can-i-remove-all-nodes-from-a-scenekit-scene) but I have no idea how to call that function in the scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the way that you want to handle the removal of your `SCNNodes` is to call the following function in your `resetFunction`:

```
self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (existingNode, _) in
    existingNode.removeFromParentNode()
}
```

Whereby `augmentedRealityView` refers to an `ARSCNView`.

You could also store specific nodes in an array of `[SCNNode]` and then loop through them to remove them e.g:

```
for addedNode in nodesAdded{

addedNode.removeFromParentNode()

}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: thx! I marked your answer because it helped me understand that I had to call that on the ARSCNView . The thread I linked in my Question had that same code but I didn't understand where to place it. The tip about storing specific nodes and removing them even answered to my next problem as well :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove all nodes use this:

```
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
    node.removeFromParentNode()
}
```

Now if you want to remove a specific node use this:

```
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
        if node.name == "textNode" {
            node.removeFromParentNode()
        }
}
```

These also works on `SCNNode` and not only `ARSCNView` which means you can loop through childNodes to a `SCNNode` and not only from the scenes `rootNode`

This is the code i use in a project. Here i first remove all `childNodes` to a node and then remove the `SCNNode` itself. Then i proceed with pausing the session, which will end it. I run the new session and finally reset the worldOrigin to the current camera position. As shapes can get the wrong angle if the startup angle of the app is off.

```
sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateHierarchy { (node, stop) in
       node.childNodes.forEach({
          $0.removeFromParentNode()
       })
       node.removeFromParentNode()
}
sceneView.session.pause()
sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: .resetTracking)
sceneView.session.setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: matrix)
```

Comment: thank you for your help! Unfortunately the other colleague answered faster with the same content. But I upvoted nonetheless because the tip about removing a node by name is certainly useful for what I planned to do next!

Comment: Ok, Thank you and good luck with your project. If you want help with anything else, write here, i have gotten pretty good knowledge about ARKit :).